# How to add Cookie to Avalonia Web Assembly

Tags: c#, .net-core, webassembly, avaloniaui, avalonia

I have been looking for a way to save data in Avalonia Web Assembly for a long time. Writing to a file does not work, because it is only created temporarily and is also gone after the end of the session.

Is it somehow possible to set a kind of cookie in the browser of Avalonia Web Assembly so that I can access my data again when I restart?

I have tried to save the data in a file (Not working because the File is gone after close). I also tried to set a browser cookie via Javascript injection, but that didn't work either, because I couldn't execute the javascript code in Avalonia.